# stop generating .png from vector drawables in api >= 21

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, drawable, android-vectordrawable

After bumping `minSdk` version to **21** and removing   `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` from build.gradle in whole project, there are png version of vector drawables in the output apk/bundle file.

**Why gradle generates png for `minSdk = 21`?**

It's in against to official document.

```
uses versions:
gradle wrapper = 7.3.3
android gradle plugin = 7.2.1
```